# In Java, how can I make a thread-safe application which reuses Git repositories?

Tags: java, multithreading, git, thread-safety, jgit

I have an open source web application where the same repository on disk can be used by multiple threads. This involves doing `git checkout` to a new branch and accessing files from within the repository.

There are a few issues with this:

- Git uses pessimistic concurrency control for operations, using a lock file in the repository. This, as expected, throws an exception in JGit when the same repository has multiple `git checkout` command called within it at once.
- The files within the repository are accessed after the command is completed and Git's lock file is removed. This means another checkout could alter the files at this stage and cause incorrect parsing of the them.

I have considered synchronised methods and semaphores as solutions to this but am not aware of the "best" solution in this context.

Comment: Sounds like a queue would work.

Comment: Actually, a queue might well work considering this scenario, with an update happening in the same repository and a different branch or path, will be rare in the application  @ChristopherSchneider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/), a pure Java implementation of Git. Using a plain Java library makes it unnecessary to provide a suitable version of Git on the server and also saves some processing cycles because it does not spawn a separate process for each Git command.

In most areas, JGit is on par with the Git CLI implementation. Thus unless you need very specific Git features, you won't see a difference.

In order to directly access the contents of a blob, the ObjectReader/ObjectLoader API can be used. For example:

```java
ObjectReader objectReader = repository.newObjectReader();
ObjectLoader objectLoader = objectReader.open( blobId );
int type = objectLoader.getType(); // Constants.OBJ_BLOB
byte[] contents = objectLoader.getBytes();
```

For more on directly accessing the Git object database, see this article: http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/10/20/git-internals/

To prevent concurrent write access, JGit uses the same lock file as Git CLI does. If write access failed due to a lock failure, JGit returns a corresponding command status that you allow application code to retry the same operation later.

If that approach of 'optimistic locking' isn't suitable for your use case, you can still resort to a work queue or other synchronization means.

Comment: I was actually already using JGit already but was accessing the local files using the regular Files API rather than using the tree/blob readers, creating the second issue in the question. Presumably this is more similar to the `git show` and as long as I only need read access will not lock the files - I will do some testing

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options, which wouldn't clobber files on disk, and thus be safer for multi-threaded treatment :

- you can directly view the content of a file without checking out an entire commit :
  from the command line, you can use :

  ```
  git show <tree-ish>:path/to/file
  ```

  or somehow find the hash for the file's content, and call :

  ```
  git cat-file -p <file-hash>
  ```

  I'm not familiar with JGit, but you can surely find a way to do either of these commands using its api
- if you have some reason to really check out a full commit, you can check out to different worktrees (see `git help worktree`),
  or maybe build an archive (`git help archive`) instead of really checking out a commit

bonus point : all of these commands also work with a bare git repo.

Comment: Thank you for the tips for utilising git better in this scenario. The only issue I see with this is that when fetching using `git show` is that: "For commits it shows the log message and textual diff" whereas I need the full contents in this situation as well

Comment: The same manpage says : "For plain blobs, it shows the plain contents." (files are named "blob" in git parlance).  What do you need from the commit objects ?

Comment: My mistake - misread the manpage - I have done some testing and it behaves as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try [scm4j-vcs-api](https://github.com/scm4j/scm4j-vcs-api). It has special feature - Locked Working Copy which is a thread- and process-safe folder

```
public static final String WORKSPACE_DIR = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "scm4j-vcs-workspaces";
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IVCSWorkspace workspace = new VCSWorkspace(WORKSPACE_DIR);
    String repoUrl = "https://github.com/scm4j/scm4j-vcs-api";
    IVCSRepositoryWorkspace repoWorkspace = workspace.getVCSRepositoryWorkspace(repoUrl);
    try (IVCSLockedWorkingCopy wc = repoWorkspace.getVCSLockedWorkingCopy()) {
        // execute git-related operations within wc.getFolder()
    }
}
```

Also see [scm4j-vcs-git](https://github.com/scm4j/scm4j-vcs-git) as an example library which executes Git operations within separated working copies